# Как удалить часть кода с помощью JS при определенном размере?

Tags: javascript, css

Доброго времени суток,

Есть блоки div polnaya
внутри разное содержимое

Их несколько, и через css media эти блоки скрываются для мобильных  экранов, но по прежнему загружаются. Хотелось бы удалять эти блоки как только размер экрана станет мобильным. Допустим ниже 1000 пикселей по ширине.

Такое можно реализовать?

Comment: Так он всё равно прогрузится до того как удалится, мне кажется этим ничего не выиграть.

Answer (score 1):

Это можно попробовать реализовать на клиенте следующим образом:

1. Оборачиваем скрываемые элементы в `<noscript>` с data-атрибутом. В значение атрибута пишем ширину вьюпорта в пикселях, начиная с которой они будут отображаться (логика типа `min-width` в медиазапросе);
2. В `head` помещаем простой скрипт, который сразу при загрузке DOM будет искать контент в noscript-обертках и либо "разворачивать" эти обертки (если ширина вьюпорта >= указанной в атрибуте), либо удалять их вместе с содержимым. Удаление в принципе не обязательно.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Demo</title>
  <script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
      const w = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
      for (let el of document.querySelectorAll('noscript[data-min-w]')) {
        if (el.dataset.minW < w)
          el.outerHTML = el.innerHTML;
        else
          el.remove();
      }
    });
  </script>
  <style>
    img { display: inline-block; max-width: 30vw; }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  <noscript data-min-w="800">
    <div class="gallery">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/2560/1920/?random&1">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/2560/1920/?random&2">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/2560/1920/?random&3">
    </div>
  </noscript>
  <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  <noscript data-min-w="800">
    <div class="gallery">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/2560/1920/?random&4">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/2560/1920/?random&5">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/2560/1920/?random&6">
    </div>
  </noscript>
</body>
</html>
```

Скрипт важно размещать текстом в теге `<script>`, а не в js-файле, и он должен быть первым (до других скриптов и стилей) - чтобы слушатель события добавился как можно раньше.

В примере используется значение ширины `800` - чтобы элементы удалялись при обычном просмотре сниппета, но показывались при нажатии "Развернуть фрагмент".

Answer (score 0):

js, как все знают, работает на клиенте. Т.е. оперирует теми данными, которые он получил от сервера. Сначала получил, потом отработал. Используйте обработку данных ещё на сервере и отдавайте необходимый объём информации в зависимости от устройства.

1 Используя стороннее расширение (http://mobiledetect.net):

```
// .php
include 'Mobile_Detect.php';
$isMobile = new Mobile_Detect();
if ($isMobile->isMobile())
    $data = 'data for mobile';
else
    $data = 'another data for desktop';
```

2 Заморочась, и написав регулярку для проверки устройства ( первая попавшаяся в поиске):

```
// .php
$mobile_agents = '!(tablet|pad|mobile|phone|symbian|android|ipod|ios|blackberry|webos)!i';
if (preg_match($mobile_agents, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) {
    $data = 'data for mobile';
} else {
    $data = 'another data for desktop';
}
```

Comment: ну или как альтернатива рендеринг на клиенте, но данные, которые сервер отправит(или клиент сам запросит), уже зависят от типа устройства

Comment: Спасибо. Попробую второй вариант